# Writing a commentary about a paper from a collaborator -- is it research misconduct?

Tags: ethics, research-misconduct

I want to write a commentary (for a journal) about a paper a collaborator has published.

Is there a conflict of interest? Is it research misconduct if I write the commentary?

Comment: Why do you think that it might be?

Comment: I don't know. I thought it might be a conflict of interest because it could be argued that I can't be completely objective.

Comment: Why would I ever write a commentary for someone who isn't a collaborator? I'm not made out of commentaries.

Comment: @J.Doe There's no such thing as complete objectivity.

Comment: Simply disclose in the commentary the fact that it is your collaborator.

Comment: Collaborator in what sense? Some funding agencies have explicit limits on time since last publication, joint grant, or co-institution together. If you only went to high school together, that probably doesn't matter. I presume that journals and conferences have similar if not identical/borrowed policies, but it depends on the venue. Contact the editor before you go to the effort of writing the whole commentary.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be "safe" just reveal the relationship. Then people can better judge whether what you have to say is just fluffing (if it is too positive) or grumpiness/sabotage (if it is too negative) or that it is a fair assessment of the other work as it should be.

---

For an explicit answer to the topline question, however, motive matters. It is possibly misconduct either to try to "catapult" the work of a collaborator or to sabotage it. Writing a fair analysis isn't misconduct.

---

Following up on a comment, if the editor thinks that writing such commentaries is a clear conflict, then you shouldn't bother to submit it. In such a case, publishing it *without* disclosing the relationship *would* be misconduct, not because of the writing of the commentary, but from the deceit of withholding information from the editor.

Comment: I previously tried to write a commentary on another one of my collaborator's papers. I disclosed it but the journal didn't like it. Do I have to disclose it again?

Comment: I think it is a good idea. If the editor objects then you can make the change. I wonder why the other journal was unhappy though.

Comment: It's the same journal and the same editor though (past and present).

Comment: Still, I wonder about the reasoning. I question whether the editor is being ethical, in fact.

Comment: The editor previously said this, "we have a strict policy against inviting authors to write commentaries on papers from researchers that they have worked very closely with because it would pose a clear conflict of interest. "

Comment: @J.Doe What answer do you want from us, then?

Comment: Ah. That changes the game. You should probably not submit it at all. See my recent edit.

Comment: I submitted the proposal and will have my coauthor disclose my relationship on my behalf. Hope that resolves the issue!